What enemies can you kill in one hit with Pure Nail?
In Hollow Knight, there are multiple different upgrades of the nail, with the strongest being the Pure Nail.
What is a full list of all the enemies that the Pure Nail can kill in one hit?

This is a list of enemies by health, and considering that Pure Nail deals 21 damage you can figure it out. But if you prefer I'll post the list as an answer.

@pinckerman if you could post it, it would be good to get an 'answer' answer.

Considering that Pure Nail deals 21 damage, and knowing the list of enemies by health, these should be the enemies that can be oneshotted:

Aluba
Ambloom
Aspid Hatching
Aspid Hunter
Aspid Mother
Baldur
Belfly
Bluggsac
Corpse Creeper
Cowardly Husk
Crawlid
Crystal Crawler
Deephunter
Deepling
Dirtcarver
Fluke Larva
Flukefey
Flukemon havles
Folly
Fool Eater
Fungified Husk
Fungling
Fungoon
Gruzzer
Gulka
Hiveling
Husk Bully
Husk Dandy
Husk Hornhead
Husk Warrior
Infected Balloon
Leaping Husk
Lifeseed
Lightseed
Maggot
Mantis Warrior
Mantis Youth
Maskfly
Manderbug
Mistake
Moss Charger
Mosscreep
Mossfly
Mosskin
Obble
Ooma
Royal Retainer
Shadow Creeper
Shardmite
Shrumal Warrior
Shrumeling
Sibling
Squit
Tiktik
Uoma
Vengefly
Volatile Mosskin
Wandering Husk
Winged Zoteling
Hopping Zoteling

